# a paper with two titles

Tags: xetex, pdftex, titles, templates, xepersian

I want to make a paper with the following format: a title, authors and abstract ; after that I want to write another title, authors and abstract. then two columns text.

Two titles are not the same.  [image].

Comment: I recommend breaking down this meta question into several smaller (narrow) separate questions (step-by-step).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I am using titling package but second title is not appearing convenient.